# Is "Speed of need" acceptable in English?

Tags: expressions

Is "Speed of need" acceptable in English?

Does it mean: "ASAP"? or it's not expression at all?

Comment: Is this an expression you heard, or an expression you made up? If you made it up, could you try to explain what you are trying to say?

Comment: I heard it in a song. i'm Ineligible to make up an expression at all, I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an expression at all (or, to be more accurate, not one I've ever heard as a native UK Eng speaker) - though in the hands of an accomplished speaker, could be made to feel like some kind of new coinage, meme, catchphrase etc.

I wouldn't use it unless you are aiming for that kind of perception. It probably wouldn't, without good context, convey precisely what you may mean.

Theoretical contextual idea...

> "Where are you going in such a hurry? Your drug dealer?"
>   "Yeah! Speed of need"

Street-speak, almost joke.
I don't see it being used in polite business conversation, unless you're discussing a possible advertising slogan.

Comment: My first thought was that it sounds like a new slogan for the Red Cross.  "The speed of sound is 770 miles per hour.  When disaster strikes, that's just too slow.  Our offices around the country begin their response within minutes.  We move at the speed of need."  (To be clear, this was the first time I had ever heard those three words put together; I'm not saying it's and AmE idiom at all.)

Comment: Yup - I'm with you, it sounded like a new slogan to me too, never heard it before.

Answer (score 4):

"Speed of need" is not an American English idiom.  It is not quite clear what it means.

"I feel a need....  A need for speed." is an American English idiom.  It describes a wish to go fast, just because it feels exhilarating to go fast.

"Haste makes waste" is another American English idiom.  It explains that hurrying can actually cause things to take longer (to do correctly).

In *The Return of the King* Tolkien uses a few expressions for moving urgently.  I think Gandalf and Pippen discussed this during their ride from Rohan to Gondor; the Rohirrim discussed this during their march from Rohan to Gondor; and various hobbits discussed this during the "raising of the Shire".

- desperate hurry
- need shall drive him
- in all haste